# how to get or insert data in mysq rds amazon from iphone application

Tags: mysql, ios, amazon-web-services

I am working app in which i want that app should connect to Mysql rds on amazon problem is that when we use simpple db they have there api and other things to connect the db and also the domain but how to connect my sql data base tables in iOS app I have search and found that they dynamicdb also so does mysql will be under dynamic db and we will access that use dynamic db api.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want an intermediary web service via which database interactions are made. 
Without this, you would need to make your database have basically no access restrictions AND embed your DB credentials in your app.  This would be extremely foolish.

Comment: I did not get can you please explain i think you are talking like we simple do make php pages and connect to db

Comment: @user3278422 it doesn't matter whether you use PHP, Java or whatever for your web service, but you should use a web service nonetheless. Think about it for a second. Would you really want to a) make your RDS database have wide open access from any connecting client in the world and b) place your DB credentials in your app where an intrepid hacker could easily get to it and use it to wipe your database clean? No you wouldn't. So you limit the DB access to an intermediate web application and then maybe have some any authentication of individual clients as necessary against this service.

Comment: This mean like we normally make web service in php and upload web service to server and access the web server to use like this instead of making the credentials in app I know using web service but if i want credentials in app then which way to do

Comment: @user3278422 Sorry. I can't help you with that. That is a dark path you are headed down.

Comment: Thanks But if i want with web service it will be same as we do normally